# crave vs crave for

Tags: phrasal-verbs, relative-pronouns

Are the following sentences with "crave" and "crave for" grammatically correct and natural in English?

> 1. He is very ambitious and is constantly craving power.
> 2. He's got a craving for power.
> 3. He has a craving for power.
> 4. Power is not something he craves.
> 5. Power is not something **that** he craves.
> 6. Power is not something **which** he craves.
> 7. Power is not something he craves **for**.
> 8. Power is not something **that** he craves **for**.
> 9. Power is not something **which** he craves **for**.
> 10. Power is not something **for which** he craves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way of knowing when to use **for** or not is to ask the question

> He is very ambitious and is constantly craving ***what***?
>   He is very ambitious and is constantly craving ***for what***?
>
> *He is very ambitious and is constantly craving* ***power.***
>   *He is very ambitious and is constantly craving* ***for power.***

or

> He's got a craving ***what***?
>   *He's got a craving* ***for power.***

> Power is not something (that/which) he craves ***for***.

The ending **for** sounds a bit odd, but is **understandable**.